# How to dynamically simplify json using java?

Tags: java, json

I have received a `json` string like so:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Order",
            "value": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Address",
            "value": "182"
        },
        {
            "name": "DNS",
            "value": "null"
        },
        {
            "name": "SSID",
            "value": "work"
        },
        {
            "name": "Protocol",
            "value": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "Key",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "carrier",
            "value": "undefined"
        },
        {
            "name": "SSH",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "ntp_addr",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Name",
            "value": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

I used stringify on an html response and this is what I have to parse. As you can see, it is pretty redundant; I would much rather `{ "Order":"2" }` than `{ "name":"Order","value":"2" }` ... So an array of name-value pairs, instead of an array of objects.

Is there a way I can dynamically format this response so that it will be easier to parse?

What 'd like is to be able to say:

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
    JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject dataObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
        String order = dataObject.getString("Order");
        String address = dataObject.getString("Address");
        // etc...
    }
```

But the current format makes it almost impossible to parse. I'd need loops within loops.

Comment: JSON - is JS object notation, `{ "name":"Order","value":"2" }` is an object with 2 properties, this `{ "Order","2" }` isn't. Did you mean `{ "Order":"2" }`

Comment: I did, my mistake.

Comment: Are you parsing this by hand or with some library/framework?

Comment: I'm using the following libraries:

Comment: import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
JSONObject simplifiedDataObject = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject dataField = data.getJSONObject(i);
    simplifiedDataObject.put(dataField.getString("name"), dataField.get("value"));
}
```

You just iterate over each element in `data`, use the `name` field as the field on a new JSONObject and simply retrieve the value using the `value` key.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to use com.google.gson library. And this response easy to parse with it:

```
private final JsonParser PARSER = new JsonParser();

public void parse(String jsonString) {
   JsonObject dataObject = PARSER.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
   JsonArray dataArray = dataObject.get("data").getAsJsonArray();
   dataArray.iterator().forEachRemaining(element -> {
      String name = element.getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();
      String value = element.getAsJsonObject().get("value").getAsString();
   }
}
```

Or you can simply use TypeAdapters for json deserialization directly in the object.